# Why does returning a stack object work?

Tags: c++, stack, return-value

The golden rules of stack objects say, that a stack object gets deleted as soon as it leaves the scope of the function.
But in fact code like this works:

```
Vec3d Vec3d::operator+(Vec3d const& vec) const{
    return Vec3d((x + vec.getX()), (y + vec.getY()), (z + vec.getZ()));
}
```

The Object that will be created on invocation is actually in stack and gets returned, and it's usable in the function which invoced the operator. So in fact it should throw an exception when i try to use my Vec3d, because it's definetly out of scope of the method of the overloaded operator.
Why does it work?
It's propably a kind of inline code, where the allocation gets moved to the function call by the compiler instead of inside the function itseld.
Or it's a copy constructor thing, where the stack object gets kinda copied as a new stack object in place of the function call...

I 'm new to c++ and trying to understand how the mechanics of c++ really work, but that's kinda confusing when you started with java :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: C++ has value semantics.

Comment: Not sure why you suggest that invalid object access will "throw an exception". Where did you hear that?

Comment: Oh sry, my fault, as is said i'm used to java where everything just throws an exception :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a *copy* of the object created on the stack, constructed using the copy constructor. You are not returning the original object.

On the other hand, if you tried to return a *pointer* to the object created on the stack, that would be very broken.

Comment: Note: The compiler is allowed to optimize away the actual copy (but you can logically think of it being copied out of the function).

Comment: @LokiAstari, That is absolutely correct. I recently saw a question answered about this. Will update the answer if I find it.